# Android Google Keep Style Reording of Views

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop

I have an app where I programmatically add several views to a linear layout.  I would like to allow the user to reorder these views but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do that.  I would like to emulate the functionality that google keep uses to reorder items in its checklists.  If someone could please point me at a working example that would be awesome.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Do you have a `LinearLayout` or a `ListView`? For Views you can use the Drag ´n Drop Gesture. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: I have a LinearLayout that I am adding my views to.  I read through that page but was still a little unclear on how to put it all together and was hoping someone had a working example.